# Menu anchored to outermost div

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I'm wondering whether it is at all possible to anchor a menu above the outermost div on a  layout?
Here is a jsFiddle I've set up: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/7/

and here's the code too:

HTML—

```
<div id="menu">Menu 1</div>
<div id="testing">Testing 1</div>

<div id="menu-right">Menu 2</div>

<div id="boxed">
<div id="box-01" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-02" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-03" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-04" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-05" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-06" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-07" class="boxes"></div>
<div id="box-08" class="boxes"></div>
</div>
```

​CSS—

```
#menu {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#menu-right {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 128px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#testing {
    font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

.boxes {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#boxed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    top: 64px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9998;
}
```

Basically I'm looking to anchor 'Menu 2' in line with the outermost red box. So, when the screen size is reduced the menu moves in 100px (width of the red boxes) so it is always in line with the box on the right. Hopefully that makes sense, I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this, not sure if I can be achieved with css or maybe it will require jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped a container around the outside, setting a max-width, changed your layout to be relative instead of absolute and employed css Float attributes to properly position everything.  I'm pretty sure this is not exactly what you want (the menu doesn't move by 100px chunks but rather moves fluidly), but here's the fiddle and the CSS changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/21/

```
#container {
    max-width: 900px;
}

#menu {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#menu-right {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#testing {
    font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.boxes {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#boxed {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    top: 64px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9998;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not quite what I'm after, thanks for your suggestion though. Do you know if it would be at all possible to move them in 100px chunk above the other box?

Comment: As the other respondent has pointed out, this will require a JavaScript framework, most likely jQuery.  My jQuery-fu is not strong enough to help you on this particular task though.  I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: no, neither is mine, still learning. Thanks for your help anyway mate!

Answer (score 0):

you can set the second menu as a child of box 4. Set boxes to position:relative and then absolutely position menu 2 above box 4 by giving it a negative top.

see your fiddle version 20

EDIT:

A quick and dirty modification of STLRick's solution with the container div will yield a reult I think you can use.

basically by wrapping the whole assembly in a container and then making the menu2 absolute to the relative container, you can absolutely position the menu2 in the top right corner of said container. As long as your layout does not change in terms of where the menus go and where the squares go, it should always be at the top right.

```
#container {
    max-width: 900px;
    position relative;
}

#menu-right {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 10px;
    right:120px;
    position: absolute;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/41/

this is really close but there are spots in the window width that are causing the box to be the wrong one, they are very small spots (2 - 5 pixles)

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/60/

and even a little closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/gL22f/5/

Comment: I tried to put that in the answer and the content filter kept telling me to make a complete answer as opposed to just give a link to jsfiddle. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @Pow-Ian this is close, but not quite what I was after. The menu is anchored to box 4, but if the screen size is bigger then box 5 or 6 may be the othermost div. I was wondering if it was possible to anchor above whichever box is furthest to the right.

Comment: then you need to use jQuery or some other frame work to make sure it is always in the last box and position above it. How are the boxes generated?

Comment: @Pow-Ian Yes, I thought it might involve jQuery. The boxes are just styled via css, they will be changed later to contain images etc. Do you know how this might be achieved with jQuery?

Comment: @Pow-Ian or actually, is it not possible to change which box the menu is a child to dependant on which box is in the top right of the screen at the time?

Comment: where there is a will there is a way. If you can figure out which box is in the top right, then you can easily swap around the menu using jQuery and the append method. If you wanted to go this route youa re going to end up counting the boxes, using their calculated width and dividing by view port to determine which box is in the top right. All of this would be in the re-size event for the window( or document I am not sure which).

Answer (score 0):

To align the menu in intervals that matches the wrapping intervals of the boxes you will need to use either media queries or javascript. I would suggest using jQuery since it will give you the most flexibility to change box-sizes without rewriting all your media query breakpoints.

Here is a snippet that I think renders the result you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Position the menu on document ready.
    positionMenu();

    // Bind it to run when the window resizes
    $(window).resize(function(){
        positionMenu();
    });
});

function positionMenu() {
    // Get the top-offset of the first box.
    var toprowoffset = $('.boxes:first').offset().top;

    // All the boxes with the same top-offset is in the top row - add class top to them.
    $('.boxes').each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('top',$(this).offset().top == toprowoffset);
    });

    // The last box in the top row is the one we want to align to.
    var alignbox = $('.boxes.top:last');

    // Calculate and set the right margin for the menu using the alignbox position.
    var marginright = $(document).width() - alignbox.position().left - alignbox.width();
    $('#menu-right').css('margin-right',marginright);
}​
```

And here is a [jsfiddle-link with it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Deq/26/)